# Is there general Linux periodic maintenance that I should be doing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, maintenance

On Windows, I used to check every so often for disk fragmentation, delete large files, defragment, check through the registry for startup entries/process hogs, etc etc.

While generally people say that Linux doesn't need defragmentation due to the difference in storage, are there other/similar maintenance tasks that I should be doing periodically to keep my computer happy, healthy, lean, and fast?

I ask both because I want to stave off disk space issues and because I have experienced performance degrading over time, and want to mitigate such speed losses as easily and cleanly as I can.

I'm running Ubuntu.

Comment: Update the software you're using. Also, upgrading ubuntu from older versions to the latest might be a good idea. But I don't usually do anything to mine.

Comment: I actually feel like every upgrade slows stuff down incrementally, until, years later, I have the decreased responsiveness of my current setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By large files I assume you mean logfiles that tend to grow. Linux mitigates this by rotating the logs using **logrotate**.

Software updates, like Muhammad pointed, are generally optional (updating for the sake of updating only isn't good, because you're updating something that just works). However, security updates are a must.

You can also run **fslint**, it will point you to misc problems with the filesystems.

Running a file integrity checker like **aide** is a good idea too. Maybe a rootkit scanner as well, if you feel yourself at danger.

Generally, you maintain a Linux system by reading the logs, maybe also having triggers for some events. Then you choose an appropriate action strategy.

Comment: No, I mean things that take up a large portion of diskspace and thus push the disk towards a state where it might become fragmented, e.g. downloads and distro iso's, for example.

Comment: I'll check out fslint, and you're right about the syslogs, that's probably something that I should check into (and try to decipher) using the system log viewer, so that's a good general thing to check.

Comment: Also checking the output of dmesg is worthwhile.

Comment: How about some links to pages about these pieces of software?

Answer (score 3):

Also, I regularly run `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get clean` to keep the package manager cleaned up.

Comment: I did not know about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- If it is a server, let him reboot once a year to let fsck check the file system
- Check your backups data integrity

Answer (score 0):

For the right maintenance do the following on a weekly basis:

1. Update your system (if possible daily).
2. Apply the tips mentioned here: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/cleaning-up-all-unnecessary-junk-files-in-ubuntu.html
3. Install a specialized cleaning program called Bleachbit from here: bleachbit.sourceforge.net/

Those are the major aspects that you must be aware of. The rest of the notes are mentioned in the previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the system logs (e.g. via System > Administration > Log File Viewer) has turned out to be especially important, since often performance problems that I'm experiencing have had a root cause obvious (though not necessarily obviously fixable) in the logs.